# [Trailhead][Apex Rest Callout] I failed run test because of JSONException

Tags: rest-api, integration, trailhead

When I studied Apex REST Callouts, I faced with JSONException in Test Callouts section. How can I solve this problem?

I made prerequisites(AnimalsCallouts.cls, Static Resource) and made test class(AnimalsCalloutsTest cls) like below:

AnimalsCallouts.cls

```
public class AnimalsCallouts {
    public static HttpResponse makeGetCallout() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
            Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            // Cast the values in the 'animals' key as a list
            List<Object> animals = (List<Object>) results.get('animals');
            System.debug('Received the following animals:');
            for (Object animal: animals) {
                System.debug(animal);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
    public static HttpResponse makePostCallout() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setBody('{"name":"mighty moose"}');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
        return response;
    }        
}
```

I uploaded txt file on Static Resource.
txt file contains below:

```
{"animals": ["pesky porcupine", "hungry hippo", "squeaky squirrel"]}
```

AnimalsCalloutsTest.cls

```
@isTest
private class AnimalsCalloutsTest {
    @isTest static  void testGetCallout() {
        // Create the mock response based on a static resource
        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
        mock.setStaticResource('GetAnimalResource');
        mock.setStatusCode(200);
        mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        // Associate the callout with a mock response
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
        // Call method to test
        HttpResponse result = AnimalsCallouts.makeGetCallout();
        // Verify mock response is not null
        System.assertNotEquals(null,result,
            'The callout returned a null response.');
        // Verify status code
        System.assertEquals(200,result.getStatusCode(),
          'The status code is not 200.');
        // Verify content type   
        System.assertEquals('application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          result.getHeader('Content-Type'),
          'The content type value is not expected.');  
        // Verify the array contains 3 items     
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) 
            JSON.deserializeUntyped(result.getBody());
        List<Object> animals = (List<Object>) results.get('animals');
        System.assertEquals(3, animals.size(),
          'The array should only contain 3 items.');          
    }   
}
```

Error Log:

```
Open Log [07L6F00005axeQqUAI]:testGetCallout System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('' (code 65279 / 0xfeff)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]
Class.System.JSON.deserializeUntyped: line 11, column 1
Class.AnimalsCallouts.makeGetCallout: line 11, column 1
Class.AnimalsCalloutsTest.testGetCallout: line 12, column 1
```

Comment: What was the MIME type for your static resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0xfeff` is the [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). This is a feature in UTF-16 that allows programs to detect which way the bytes were written (big-endian vs little-endian). However, Salesforce uses UTF-8, which does not require a BOM, and can indeed cause errors like this to occur. To fix this, you will want to replace the original file with a file saved in ASCII (ISO-8859-1/Latin) instead. Your code should work just fine after you fix the file's internal format.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox.
I replace the original file with a file saved in ANSI instead.
It works !